# Relacion Uno a Uno en Spring JPA no migra la clave externa

Tags: mysql, hibernate, java-ee, jpa, spring-boot

Tengo dos entidades en mi proyecto Spring Boot que usa Spring JPA y una base de datos MySQL con Hibernate. Esas dos entidades están relacionadas con una relacion Una a Una. EL problema es que cuando intento añadir un tipo de objetos, no se migra la clave primaria de al otro objeto relacionado.

Esta es una de mis entidades:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "tank")
public class Tank {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "level_sensor_id")
    private LevelSensor levelSensor;

    public LevelSensor getLevelSensor() {
        return levelSensor;
    }

    public void setLevelSensor(LevelSensor levelSensor) {
        this.levelSensor = levelSensor;
    }
}
```

Y esta es la otra entidad:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "level_sensor")
public class LevelSensor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="levelSensor", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Tank tank;
}
```

Estoy intentando añadir un nuevo LevelSensor a un Tank ya existente. Para ello tengo el siguiente controlador:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/levelSensor/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addLevelSensor(           
            @RequestBody LevelSensorDTO levelSensorDTO,
            @RequestHeader("Accept") String acceptHeader, HttpSession session) {

        LevelSensor newLevelSensor= new LevelSensor();

        Tank tank = tankService.getTankById(levelSensorDTO.getTankId());

        newLevelSensor.setTank(tank);

        newLevelSensor = levelSensorService.saveLevelSensor(newLevelSensor);        

        log.info("The level sensor : "+ levelSensorDTO.toString() +" was successfully added");

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(null ,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Aunque le digo al LevelSensor cual es su tank no me rellena la relación externa en el Tank, por lo que crea el LevelSensor pero no se relaciona con el Tank.

Se puede corregir, para ello, lo que puedo hacer es, una vez añadido el level sensor, puedo editar el tanque y asignarle el level sensor recien creado. Sin embargo es una solución que no me gusta y que no entiendo ya que entonces tengo editar dos objetos cuando creo que con editar uno debería ser suficiente.

Me podríais echar un mano o aconsejarme? Puede ser que la relación esté mal¿

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Javier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tienes una relación "one to one", jpa por defecto considera que el fetchType es "eager", esto significa que la entidad hija es cargada en la entidad padre por defecto. 
Para definir bien tu relación, tienes que definir cuál es la entidad padre de la relación y cuál es la hija. En el caso de la entidad padre es donde realizas el mappedBy y el cascade dentro de tu `@OneToOne` y en este cascade es donde está tu error. Lo estás poniendo en las dos entidades (y yo intuyo por el código que tu relación no es bidireccional porque estás tratando a tu entidad LevelSensor como la padre).

En una entidad estás declarando `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` y en la otra `cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST`

el atributo Cascade lo que hace es decirle a jpa como debe comportarse en la relación entre la entidad padre y la entidad hija, por tanto, al decirle que el cascadeType es persist implica que solo "utiliza" la relación entre las dos entidades a la hora de persistir en base de datos y no en el resto de operaciones. Lo ideal es utilizar el all en esta entidad para que considere ese atributo como una entidad hija en el resto de operaciones también, se puede encontrar más info sobre esta propiedad aquí:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqm/index.html

Con esto hecho, te diré que hibernate sabe perfectamente tratar tu entidad hija y (simplemente teniendo ese atributo relleno con un id existente) jpa sabe perfectamente como mapear esa relación y te dará la excepción correspondiente en caso de que intentes violarla.